# How to sort list type generic if more than one property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics

I have a list-generic that has a property (class type). I need a sort method for Z parameters (TrainingSet):

```
public override List<TrainingSet> CalculatedDistancesArray
    (List<TrainigSet> ts, double x, double y, int k)
{
    for (int i =0; i < ts.Count; i++)
    {
        ts[i].Z = (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((ts[i].X - x), 2) 
                  + Math.Pow((ts[i].Y - y), 2)));
    }
    // I want to sort according to Z
    ts.Sort(); //Failed to compare two elements in the array.
    List<TrainingSet> sortedlist = new List<TrainingSet>();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        sortedlist.Add(ts[i]);
    }
    return ts;
}

public class TrainigSet
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
    public string Risk { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note that there are easier ways of copying a list, by the way - and did you really mean to sort the *input* list and then copy it to a new list?

Comment: He's not copying the entire list, only the first k items.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just sorting on a single property is easy. Use the overload which takes a `Comparison<T>`:

```
// C# 2
ts.Sort(delegate (TrainingSet o1, TrainingSet o2) 
       { return o1.Z.CompareTo(o2.Z)); }
);

// C# 3
ts.Sort((o1, o2) => o1.Z.CompareTo(o2.Z));
```

Sorting on multiple properties is a bit trickier. I've got classes to build up comparisons in a compound manner, as well as building "projection comparisons" but if you really only want to sort by Z then the above code is going to be as easy as it gets.

If you're using .NET 3.5 and you don't really need the list to be sorted in-place, you can use OrderBy and ThenBy, e.g.

```
return ts.OrderBy(t => t.Z);
```

or for a more complicated comparison:

```
return ts.OrderBy(t => t.Z).ThenBy(t => t.X);
```

These would be represented by `orderby` clauses in a query expression:

```
return from t in ts
       orderby t.Z
       select t;
```

and

```
return from t in ts
       orderby t.Z, t.X
       select t;
```

(You can also sort in a descending manner if you want.)

Answer (score 3):

```
var sortedList = 
      list.OrderBy(i => i.X).ThenBy(i => i.Y).ThenBy(i => i.Z).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't sort the list in place, which the OP *may* want - it's not clear.

Comment: @ykaratoprak: See Jon Skeet's answer. He has a 2.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. It worked for me:

```
ts.Sort(delegate(TrainingSet a, TrainingSet b) { return a.X.CompareTo(b.X) != 0 ? a.X.CompareTo(b.X) : a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using framework 3.5 this would simply be:

```
public override List<TrainingSet> CalculatedDistancesArray(List<TrainigSet> ts, double x, double y, int k) {
   foreach (TrainigSet t in ts) {
      t.Z = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(t.X - x, 2) + Math.Pow(t.Y - y, 2));
   }
   return ts.OrderBy(t => t.Z).Take(k).ToList();
}
```

Note: This will not change the order of the ts list, but create a new, sorted list to return.

(I assume that you actually wanted to return the first k items from the list, not the ts list as you do in the code in your question.)

Using framework 2 needs a little more code:

```
public override List<TrainingSet> CalculatedDistancesArray(List<TrainigSet> ts, double x, double y, int k) {
   foreach (TrainigSet t in ts) {
      t.Z = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(t.X - x, 2) + Math.Pow(t.Y - y, 2));
   }
   ts.Sort(delegate (TrainigSet t1, TrainigSet t2) { return t1.Z.CompareTo(t2.Z)); });
   List<TrainigSet> result = new List<TrainigSet>(k);
   for (int i = 0; i < k ; i++) {
      result.Add(ts[i]);
   }
   return result;
}
```

If you are using the Z value only for the sorting, you could skip the `Math.Sqrt` call and just leave the value to be the square of the distance, as that sorts exactly the same as the distance.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use the Sort method on the list if you implement IComparable<TrainingSet> on your type "TrainingSet". You will have to implement a "CompareTo" method. You can then simply delegate your implementation to the "CompareTo" of your double-typed Z. This will avoid your exception.