# c# tuple list multiple sort in order

Tags: c#, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuple like this:
List<Tuple<int, char, string>  ws= new List<Tuple<int, char,string>>();

I get output like this:

```
7 'S': And on silentious porpoises, whose snouts
6 'E': One eats one pate, even of salt, quotha.
6 'I': Of snails, musician of pears, principium
6 'T': It was not so much the lost terrestrial,
6 'E': Berries of villages, a barber's eye,
5 'E': The sovereign ghost. As such, the Socrates
5 'A': The snug hibernal from that sea and salt,
5 'E': Preceptor to the sea? Crispin at sea
5 'I': Nota: man is the intelligence of his soil,
5 'E': An eye most apt in gelatines and jupes,
```

but i would like output like :

```
7 'S': And on silentious porpoises, whose snouts
6 'E': Berries of villages, a barber's eye,
6 'T': It was not so much the lost terrestrial,
6 'I': Of snails, musician of pears, principium
6 'E': One eats one pate, even of salt, quotha.
6 'S': The sovereign ghost. As such, the Socrates
5 'E': An eye most apt in gelatines and jupes,
5 'I': Nota: man is the intelligence of his soil,
5 'O': On porpoises, instead of apricots,
5 'E': Preceptor to the sea? Crispin at sea
```

So somehow arrange in descending order with item 1 and where item1 is equal arrange in ascending order with item3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort list type generic if more than one property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842998/how-to-sort-list-type-generic-if-more-than-one-property)

Comment: @PeterDuniho That will work, but it's from 2009 and predates all the built-in linq and tuple support they've added to the language.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I have no idea what you mean. The accepted answer to that question includes exactly the solution you proposed in your answer below, as does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843005) also found on the duplicate. Even if it didn't (and I reiterate, **it does**), that doesn't keep this question from being a duplicate. It just means you have the opportunity to add a new answer to _that_ question.

Comment: Yes thanks soo much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ws.OrderByDescending(i => i.Item1).ThenBy(i => i.Item3)
```

It won't actually change the list, but you can use it at the point where you want to output items.

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/UzD1CI